# Left join in Entity Framework with 1-to-many relation

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have five tables:

```
Coupons
Coupon_Redemptions
User_Coupon
Wash
Account
```

This is `SQL Query` that works in `SQL Server` and `Entity Raw SQL`, but can't get it to work with `LINQ` because `1-to-many` releations, with lazy loading can't manage to get it because User_coupons, Wash... are collections.

```
SELECT 
    C.Id AS "CouponId", C.Coupon_code AS "CouponCode", 
    C.Discount_amount AS "DiscountAmount", 
    C.Valid_for_all AS "ValidForAll", C.Expiration_date AS "ExpirationDate", 
    R.Redemption_date AS "RedemptionDate",
    U.Date_added AS "DateAddedToUser", W.Id AS "WashId", A.Name  
FROM 
    Coupon C
    LEFT JOIN User_coupon U on U.CouponId = C.Id
    LEFT JOIN Coupon_redemption R on R.CouponId = C.Id
    LEFT JOIN Wash W on W.CouponId = C.Id
    LEFT JOIN Account A on U.AccountId = A.Id
```

Here is snippet of Relation diagram [image]

Tried variation on this query, it returns one row. But it looks perfect.

```
var results =
                from c in db.Coupons
                from u in c.User_coupon.DefaultIfEmpty()
                from r in c.Coupon_redemption.DefaultIfEmpty()
                from w in c.Washes.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new {
                    CouponId = c.Id,
                    CouponCode = c.Coupon_code,
                    DiscountAmount = c.Discount_amount,
                    ValidForAll = c.Valid_for_all,
                    ExpirationDate = c.Expiration_date,
                    RedemptionDate = r.Redemption_date,
                    DateAddedToUser = u.Date_added,
                    WashId = w.Id
                };
```

Result to String:

```
SELECT[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[Coupon_code] AS [Coupon_code], [Extent1].[Discount_amount] AS [Discount_amount], [Extent1].[Valid_for_all] AS [Valid_for_all], [Extent1].[Expiration_date] AS [Expiration_date], [Extent3].[Redemption_date] AS [Redemption_date], [Extent2].[Date_added] AS [Date_added], [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id1] 
FROM [dbo].[Coupon] AS [Extent1] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[User_coupon] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[CouponId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Coupon_redemption] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent3].[CouponId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Wash] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent4].[CouponId]
```

Comment: any question, error message ? do you use code first, db first ?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, they are collections (with or without lazy loading) when the object containing them is *materialized* (i.e. you work through object instance). When used inside LINQ to Entities queries, they are simple table navigations (joins).

The rules are simple. To get the equivalent of SQL inner join for collection navigation property, you use

```
from child in parent.Collection
```

and respectively for left outer join:

```
from child in parent.Collection.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

For reference navigation property you can't specify explicitly the type of the join - it depends on (is controlled by) whether the relationship is required or optional. And instead of `from`, you can use `let` or directly the navigation property to get the SQL query join equivalent.

With that being said, the equivalent LINQ query would be something like this:

```
var query = 
    from c in dbContext.Coupons
    from u in c.User_coupon.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from r in c.Coupon_redemptions.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from w in c.Washes.DefaultIfEmpty()
    let a = u.Account
    select new
    {
        CouponId = c.Id,
        CouponCode = c.Coupon_code,
        DiscountAmount = c.Discount_amount,
        ValidForAll = c.Valid_for_all,
        ExpirationDate = c.Expiration_date, 
        RedemptionDate = r.Redemption_date,
        DateAddedToUser = u.Date_added,
        WashId = w.Id,
        Name = a.Name,          
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. This query returns only one record. With All Data(meaning that returning if they have a match) I'm trying to return equivalent to SQL query that returns me ALL coupons and all of releated tables, Null if empty, value if not. But I need all coupons with data from others whether or not they exists.

Comment: This should do (with left outer joins). If you say `query.ToString()`, what do you see?

Comment: I edited my Question, can't fit it here. It's all looks perfect. :/

Comment: Looks good, isn't it? Are you sure you don't have some filter (`Where`) not shown there. I don't see how that could return single row (assuming the table `Coupon` has multiple records) w/o some filter. Where is the join to Account, I don't see it.

Comment: Problem is nullable WashId. I added != null and it works. I missed error in Events on Laptops small screen. :/ Thank you Ivan, you helped me understand LINQ Joins. It's really simple now. :)

Comment: Ivan, are you there, I need small help about LINQ, question is connected with this Question here.

Comment: @Boris Sure, what's the issue?

Comment: I posted it like a question, you know LINQ well - check it out.